# Error: Class kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.FunctionCaller$FieldSetter

Tags: java, android, kotlin, androidx

I've tried everything to get rid of this error but it keeps coming back.

```
Class kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.FunctionCaller$FieldSetter can not access a member of class com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ManifestProcessorTask with modifiers "private"
```

__

```
  org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer$TaskCreationException: Could not create task ':app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer.taskCreationException(DefaultTaskContainer.java:673)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer.access$600(DefaultTaskContainer.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer$TaskCreatingProvider$1.run(DefaultTaskContainer.java:649)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer$TaskCreatingProvider.getOrNull(DefaultTaskContainer.java:632)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer$TaskCreatingProvider.getOrNull(DefaultTaskContainer.java:596)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultNamedDomainObjectCollection.findByName(DefaultNamedDomainObjectCollection.java:279)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer.findByName(DefaultTaskContainer.java:523)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer.findByName(DefaultTaskContainer.java:74)
    at org.gradle.plugins.ide.internal.tooling.GradleProjectBuilder.tasks(GradleProjectBuilder.java:82)
    at org.gradle.plugins.ide.internal.tooling.GradleProjectBuilder.buildHierarchy(GradleProjectBuilder.java:68)
    at org.gradle.plugins.ide.internal.tooling.GradleProjectBuilder.buildHierarchy(GradleProjectBuilder.java:56)
    at org.gradle.plugins.ide.internal.tooling.GradleProjectBuilder.buildAll(GradleProjectBuilder.java:46)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.DefaultBuildController.getModel(DefaultBuildController.java:79)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.InternalBuildActionAdapter$2.getModel(InternalBuildActionAdapter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.BuildControllerAdapter.getModel(BuildControllerAdapter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.AbstractBuildController.findModel(AbstractBuildController.java:57)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.AbstractBuildController.findModel(AbstractBuildController.java:44)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.run.OutputBuildAction.execute(OutputBuildAction.java:55)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.run.OutputBuildAction.execute(OutputBuildAction.java:42)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.InternalBuildActionAdapter.execute(InternalBuildActionAdapter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.buildResult(ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:81)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.access$100(ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:38)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner$1.buildFinished(ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor49.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.DefaultListenerManager$ListenerDetails.dispatch(DefaultListenerManager.java:370)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.DefaultListenerManager$ListenerDetails.dispatch(DefaultListenerManager.java:352)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:58)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.DefaultListenerManager$EventBroadcast$ListenerDispatch.dispatch(DefaultListenerManager.java:340)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.DefaultListenerManager$EventBroadcast$ListenerDispatch.dispatch(DefaultListenerManager.java:327)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:42)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:230)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:149)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:58)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:324)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:234)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:140)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy16.buildFinished(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.finishBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:165)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.finishBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:131)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:150)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.executeTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:124)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:77)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:74)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:154)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:96)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:74)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.run(ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:50)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:45)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:51)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$1.transform(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$1.transform(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:79)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:31)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:62)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:81)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:295)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: kotlin.reflect.full.IllegalCallableAccessException: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.FunctionCaller$FieldSetter can not access a member of class com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ManifestProcessorTask with modifiers "private"
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KCallableImpl.call(KCallableImpl.kt:205)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.TaskArtifactsHolder$InputFilesInjectPoint.inject(TaskArtifactsHolder.kt:109)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.TaskArtifactsHolder.transfer(TaskArtifactsHolder.kt:90)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.AnnotationProcessingTaskCreationAction.configure(AnnotationProcessingTaskCreationAction.kt:47)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessTestManifest$CreationAction.configure(ProcessTestManifest.java:310)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessTestManifest$CreationAction.configure(ProcessTestManifest.java:275)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.factory.TaskAction.execute(TaskFactoryUtils.kt:83)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.factory.TaskAction.execute(TaskFactoryUtils.kt:71)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.BuildOperationCrossProjectConfigurator$4.execute(BuildOperationCrossProjectConfigurator.java:108)
    at org.gradle.internal.ImmutableActionSet$SetWithFewActions.execute(ImmutableActionSet.java:285)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.doAdd(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:244)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.add(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:238)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultNamedDomainObjectCollection.add(DefaultNamedDomainObjectCollection.java:117)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer.access$2500(DefaultTaskContainer.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer$TaskCreatingProvider$1.run(DefaultTaskContainer.java:645)
    ... 118 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.FunctionCaller$FieldSetter can not access a member of class com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ManifestProcessorTask with modifiers "private"
    at sun.reflect.Reflection.ensureMemberAccess(Reflection.java:102)
    at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.slowCheckMemberAccess(AccessibleObject.java:296)
    at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkAccess(AccessibleObject.java:288)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:761)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.FunctionCaller$FieldSetter.call(FunctionCaller.kt:185)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KCallableImpl.call(KCallableImpl.kt:106)
    ... 132 more
```

I don't even use kotlin.

**What I've tried:**

Delete all the files inside **.gradle** and the **Invalidate Caches / Restart**

Update the Kotlin to **1.3.0-rc-57-Studio3.3-1**

Update the Android Studio to **Android Studio 3.3 Canary 11**
Build #AI-182.4323.46.33.5012296

Update Gradle to **gradle-4.10-all**

After all of each step, I was able to run a build 4/5 times and then the error comes back.
This is destroying my workflow I would really appreciate some help

EDIT: (Probably was the cause of the error) Because the error started after I tried to update the android dependencies to **AndroidX** but then I gave up because I kept getting errors (With Glide and @NonNull) so decided to downgrade back to **android 28.0.0-rc02**

Comment: Facing same issue. Have you find any solution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facing same issue. I resolve this error by doing this:

Earlier in my build.gradle (Project : appname)

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0-alpha12'
```

I use 3.2.0 instead of 3.3.0-alpha12

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
```

Try this

Happy coding :)

Comment: I kinda made the error go away a few days ago, was only waiting to see if it would come back to post an answer, but this might solve the problem as well. I'm on build:gradle:3.3.0-alpha11

Comment: probably you need to decrease that version.No issue it may help other developers. Thank you :)

Comment: Looks like after 7 days the problem came back to hunt me, but I downgraded the Gradle version as you suggested and it went away. Let's see for how long.

Answer (score 6):

A few days ago I tried this and the problem hasn't come back ever since:

---

Delete all the files in **.Gradle**

Execute Build > **Clean Project**

File > **Invalidate Caches / Restart...**

(After restart) **Sync Project with Gradle Files**

---

All of this steps must be done without making anything in between otherwise somehow will not work.

Comment: Worked for me with also build-tools 3.3.0-alpha12

Comment: it works but it will happen again anytime soon so it's not a permanent fix :s

Answer (score 0):

Faced this issue but I've changed in `build.gradle` in project

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0-alpha01'
```

with this latest

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0-rc02'
```

happy coding